# jQuery: Moving element to another element and back again renders the element unclickable

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my script, I'm attempting to move an element (list) from one parent (just the text) to another and then back again (to the list). The problem is that when I have moved the element back to the original parent (ul), it has become un-clickable. I thought using the detach() over the remove() might do the trick but it doesn't make a difference.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#inventoryWeapon li").click(function(event) { 
    var clickedId = event.target.id;
    if ($("td#weapon").is(":empty")) {
      $("td#weapon").text(clickedId); 
      $(this).detach(); 
    }
  });
  $("td#weapon").click(function(event) { 
    var unequipping = $(this).text();
    $("#inventoryWeapon").append("<li id='" + unequipping + "'>" + unequipping + "</li>"); 
    $(this).detach();
  });
});
```

Comment: You're not moving the element, you're creating a new element.

Comment: Event delegation would go a long way toward simplifying this code.

Comment: Instead of moving elements, why don't you just hide and show them?

Comment: @Barmar, I'm looking to change the contents of one element into another. Though, that does give me a few ideas.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the popular comment above, you are not moving the element. To move it, do this.

```
$("td#weapon").click(function(event) {
    $(this).appendTo($("#inventoryWeapon"));
});
```

Comment: I totally missed that. Thanks! With this solution, I also noticed that I was pulling the 'td' element from it's table and pushing it back into the 'li' element which was causing the re-instated elements of '#inventoryWeapon li' to be un-clickable.
I'd upvote this solution but I'm a few points shy of that ability.

Answer (score 2):

You're not moving the element, you're removing the element in one function, and creating a new element with the same ID and content in the other. But the original event handler was only bound to the original element.

If you want your event handler to work with dynamically created elements, use event delegation:

```
$("#inventoryWeapon").on("click", "li", function(event) {
    ...
});
```

Alternatively, you could save the element when you detach it, instead of recreating it:

```
var savedLI;
$("#inventoryWeapon li").click(function() {
    if ($("td#weapon").is(":empty")) {
        savedLI = $(this).detach();
        $("td#weapon").text(this.id);
    }
});
$("td#weapon").click(function() {
    if (savedLI) {
        $("#inventoryWeapon").append(savedLI);
        $(this).detach();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmm, I may use this tidbit for something else later. Thanks!